# Cloudamqp amqp-client.js connection recovery

Tags: cloudamqp, amqp-client

I am integrating the [ampq-client](https://github.com/cloudamqp/amqp-client.js) into my javaScript application but I am wondering how this library handles recovery in case of network failures. I do not see any options for recovery and after a simple test, it seems it does not recover.

I want to ask:

=> Does this library include some options for automatic recovery?

=> If not, what are the best practices to handle the recovery manually? If the connection is lost, I will need to reconnect and re-do all consumers only ?

Thank you for any help